# How did Madara pull the Meteor stunt?

Tags: naruto

During the 4th Great Ninja War, Madara caused a supersized meteor to fall on the entire battlefield.
[image]

How was this possible? The *wiki* states that he summoned a meteorite, but that can't be true, he never weaved any signs for summoning, or at least the Susanoo's hand seal does not resemble the ones for summoning.
[image]

Can anyone clarify how this happened? Is this a Susano'o-only Jutsu? Or is it more like Madara's Sharingan ocular power?

Comment: He did handsign, 3 handsigns to be precise. Madara himself did 1 handsign, and then his four-armed Susanoo did 2 handsigns to perform this technique

Comment: It's a Rinnegan summoning technique.He used his Sussano for the hand seals.

Comment: ooh wow thats true @Albert he actual did a handseal along with his Susanooo. But then that doesn't add up. The Rinnengan can use the power of the animal path to summon weird  beasts which also possess the rinnengan. However, how could madara suddenly summon a meteorite? On first glance i thought it was a planetary devastation but then it can't be since he didn't make it

Comment: @TheAnimeScientist My guess is that was something like a Universal Pull. He pulled meteorites from the outer space. He needed so much chakra to pull something from space, that's why he made his Susanoo did the handsigns too

Comment: While not named in the manga and anime, it was named in Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 3 as "Tengai Shinsei". Additionally, that's a meteor, not a meteorite.

Comment: @кяαzєя okay I didn't know the difference between meteor and meteorites, thx for the info. For the naming, we can argue that different name doesn't always mean different jutsu. Sasuke named his change-shaped-amaterasu as blaze release. My argument is that "Tengai Shinsei" is still a form of Universal Pull, pulling meteor from space.

Comment: @TheAnimeScientist another possibility: Tengai Shinsei was Madara's unique Mangekyou ability. Just like Tsukuyomi to Itachi, Kamui to Obito and Amaterasu to Itachi and Sasuke. They never mentioned about Madara's unique Mangekyou ability in canon resources, so, maybe ..

Comment: Don't talk about Sasuke having Amaterasu.Itachi implanted it in his eyes,I guess if Itachi hadn't done that he would probably be without any abilities like Madara

Comment: After all Madara and Sasuke were both similar Indra reincarnates.

Answer (score 2):

He used the Rinnegan Deva path to pull the meteor out of space. The Deva path uses push and pull so you can push rocks from the earth to the sky making a black moon, meteor, or meteorite thing whatever. He then uses the pull part to crash it down making chibaku tensei. Maybe he pull the meteor towards earth but it would have destroyed his chakra if he did it so he used some of the susanoo chakra to pull of this stunt.

Comment: The susanoo is the manifestation of an Uchihas chakra I think. Not a separate entity

Comment: It is a sort of seperate energy not separate entity. Kind of like a tailed beast. The sharingan isn't part of the users energy, it's another energy that's  able to be passed down. I call it the law of Dojutsu. For all dojutsu. A different energy without a conscious so the uchiha takes over that energy. Madara needed to use the rinnegan to pull down that meteor. He decided that if he drew some sharingan energy from a susanoo and converted it along with the rinnegan and normal chakra, It will use less energy from each faction.. That is my hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

This dojutsu is **rinnegan+ms** ocular jutsu. During the fight,madara used rinnegan for **shinsei tengai**.Plus Hand seals are needed to perform this jutsu.It could be that Mangekyō is needed to perform hand seals.As stated above by other content providers, Rinnegan Deva path is required to pull the meteor out of space.

Answer (score 0):

His susanoo also made handseals along with him.

Just like how Sasuke uses Susanoo: Chidori, He might have used a Susanoo amped Bansho Tenin (Rinngean Deva path Pull) which's range was extended to the outer atmosphere and pulled down a meteor.

Or there are theories that it might be his Mangekyou Sharingan ability.